# 405 Method not allowed on express angular 5 app deployed using azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, angular5

I deployed my angular + nodejs app using azure web app but i get 405 method not allowed error while trying to access my node api

server.js static assets code

```
/*API routes*/
const api = require("./server/routes/route");

/*Enable cors origin*/
var corsOptions = {
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));

app.use("/api", api);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/index.html"));
});
```

since i am using iis i have added a web.config in root of dist folder as this gist

> https://gist.github.com/iammelvin/62e2582796cbc3fa8b5fc9e242915788

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <webSocket enabled="false" />

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I build the project using build script

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "concurrently  \"nodemon --inspect-brk=3000 server.js --watch server\" \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json\""
  },
```

my angular cli json looks something like this

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets", "favicon.ico"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app"...}]
```

and finally my index base href is `<base href="/">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the `web.config` file is put in the root of your app (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`).

Based on your `web.config`, your folder structure should look something like this:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot
├── node_modules 
│   └── ...
├── public
│   └── ...
├── server.js
├── package.json
└── web.config
```

Actually, you no longer need these lines in your server.js file:

```
// remove these lines of the code as well
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/index.html"));
});
```

Now, you can access your express route with this endpoint:

> https://{yourWebAppName}.azurewebsites.net/api/{routeName}

And retrieve the static file with this endpoint:

> https://{yourWebAppName}.azurewebsites.net/{theFileInPublic}

Comment: so i have to add them via ftp ? Won't azure app extension in vs code do that if i add a web.config in dist root ? In that case will i get ftp details from azure if my app plan is basic ?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp.md#step-2-get-ftp-connection-information) to get FTP details or you can use Kudu cmd (https://<yourwebappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole) to operate the remote files of your app.

Comment: i tried adding web.config in wwwroot folder but i get this error 'page not found' all the files inside my dist folder are also in the wwwroot folder.Btw should i add reference server.js in src/index.html ?? src is the folder where i have client app files.

Comment: No, You shouldn't. Based on this line `<action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>` in the web.config, you'll need put the static files into `/public` folder or just rename `src` to `public`.

Comment: so I should create a folder named public in wwwroot and put the files inside them ??

Comment: Yes, your **static** files such as front-end js, css and html files should be located in /public folder, and then you can make a call via browser (https://<yourWebAppName>.azurewebsites.net/<theFileInPublic>) to visit them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165129/discussion-between-melvin-and-aaron-chen).